# How do I get Visual Studio to automatically generate a function declaration for me based on a function call?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to write a function call and have Visual Studio generate it's declaration for me. The World object has no **logCharacterMovement** method in the code below:

```
Class Enemy(){
    private:
        World* worldItResidesIn;
    public
        void takeYourTurn(){
            //let's say some movement logic is here
            worldItResidesIn->logCharacterMovement("enemy", std::make_pair(oldXPos, oldYPos), std::make_pair(newXPos, newYPos));
        }       
}
```

Here is the method declaration I'd like Visual Studio to create inside the world class:

```
Class World(){
        void logCharacterMovement(const char*, std::pair<int,int>, std::pair<int,int>);
}
```

I'm like 99% sure this is possible, possibly using the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Without extensions, it is not possible for C++.

Comment: Visual Assist will help at this but its paid software.

Comment: What's wrong with just typing it in?  Since there are multiple possibilities for every parameter you'd probably need to customize it anyway.  (`const char *`, `std::string`, `const std::string &` or any other class that can be implicitly constructed from a character string for parameter 1; `std::pair<int, int>`, `const std::pair<int, int> &`, or variations with other types, for the other two parameters.)

Comment: That's a good point. I usually have to alter the function signature after using this feature in Visual Assist.

Comment: Have you considered leveraging a custom code snippet. 

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019

Comment: This is what expansion should do, this is really a good function, but not a good habit of writing C++ code.